# How to specify a monkey patched class in the typescript definitions file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-definitions

Say I have a class `A`:

```js
class A {
    constructor();

    someFunction(): void;
}
```

and a class `B` where I expect an instance of class `A` as a property:

```js
class B {
    aProperty: A;
}
```

How can I define typescript definitions (`.d.ts`) for a class `C` with a property of class `A` that is monkey patched to also include a function `someOtherFunction(): void;`?

#### Additional information

In class `C` class `A` effectively looks like this:

```js
class A {
    constructor();

    someFunction(): void;
    someOtherFunction(): void;
}
```

I tried to define class `C` as follows without any luck:

```js
class C {
    aProperty: A | { someOtherFunction(): void; };
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine https://tsplay.dev/WKr7om

Comment: @Konrad - You've included `someOtherFunction` in the declaration of `A`. I think the OP means that it isn't in that type, like this: https://tsplay.dev/WJrRZW

Comment: `aProperty: A & { someOtherFunction(): void; };` works https://tsplay.dev/wjp42m

Comment: @Konrad - Very good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've monkey-patched the class, then it has the new method wherever it's used. You can make the types reflect that by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#handbook-content):

```
interface A {
    someOtherFunction(): void;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQgewLYFMBiArgHbAAuAlhkQBQCUAXNAG4bkAmiKa3A9D9F1QBfJCKTkipHACcAZmGA44nbplwB5UgAsZhEhSp1GLdgG5RSJKEgwAwirRgACtIwAHGaQCeAQkbwAH0R0bBxNHWk9MkoaBmZWNlNoIXMxYCoIUmhgaABeaCIcAHdoWzpzKwA6Z1cPaW9KtTDtXWJow1pzIA)

That will merge with the types for `class A` to make `someOtherFunction` available on instances of `A` (from a type perspective; the monkey-patching is necessary for it to be true from a runtime perspective).

I don't know that you can scope it, though. As [Konrad pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282347/how-to-specify-a-monkey-patched-class-in-the-typescript-definitions-file#comment136243983_77282347), you can use an intersection rather than a union for the property (`aProperty: A & { someOtherFunction(): void; };`). But again, if it's monkey-patched, it's monkey-patched everywhere. :-)